# var_dump $_GET return null or not worked in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i'm have a problem  with  GET request  in  wordpress 
when i'm

```
 $post_ide = $_GET['post-id'] ;


 var_dump($_GET['post-id']);
```

when i'm go to the linke example.com/?post-id=300  i'm have this linke examole.com without GET post-id and var_dump return null

can anyone help me ??
thank you

Comment: try example.com?post-id=300 instead of example.com/?post-id=300

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the hyphen in the variable name use example.com/?post_id=300 and

```
$post_id = $_GET['post_id'];
var_dump( $post_id );
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but the same return null i'm think that the GET request blocked if use any get request and use var_dump return null

Comment: @mhmdshaheen I tested this on my own WP setup and it works (the 'post-id' doesn't). Where are you placing the code?

Comment: Do you have any custom rewrite rules that might be removing the variable from the url? You should also possibly be using the single post template https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#single-post instead of a page template if you are trying to display data for a single post.

Comment: this my problim removing the variable from the url but i'm make a new .htaccess with the defult wordpress but the same problem and i have disable all plugin's ,  and i'm know the single post but i'm need this page for another worke

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$post_ide = get_query_var('post-id');
```